# Angular DI Unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use DI with Angular, but I'm stuck as I get error

```
Error: Unknown provider: dataServiceProvider <- dataService
```

Here is my Main.js:

```
var app = {};

app.angularModule = angular.module('TestWeb', []);

app.angularModule.value("breeze", window.breeze);
app.angularModule.value("toastr", window.toastr);
```

Here is part of my logger:

```
app.angularModule.factory('logger', function (toastr, $window) {

    toastr.options.timeOut = 2000; // 2 second toast timeout
    toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';

    var logger = {
        error: error,
        info: info,
        success: success,
        warning: warning,
        log: log // straight to console; bypass toast
    };
```

Here is part of my DataService:

```
app.angularModule.factory = ('dataService', function (breeze, logger) {

    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);


    var mbservice = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: "http://localhost:23758/api/",
        hasServerMetadata: false,
    });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: mbservice });

    manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

    var dataService = {
        getAll: getAll,
        createItem: createItem,
        saveChanges: saveChanges,

    };
```

Here is part  my sample controller:

```
app.angularModule.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, breeze, dataService, logger) {

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.getAll = function() {
        dataService.getAll("tests")
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
    };

    $scope.getAll();
```

And here is part of html:

Here is full error

```
Error: Unknown provider: dataServiceProvider <- dataService
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2734:15
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2862:39)
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2739:45
    at getService (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2862:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2880:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:2914:23)
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4805:24
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:4384:17
    at forEach (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:137:20) angular.js:5754
(anonymous function) angular.js:5754
```

Note:

I'm following breeze sample ToDO Angular with DI : [link](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo) and I am using DI same as they are. but I get errors, and don't know why.

Comment: `app.angularModule.factory = ('dataService', function (breeze, logger) {` is invalid factory syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the difference between your definition of the logger factory and the data service factory:

```
app.angularModule.factory('logger', function (toastr, $window) {
```

vs.

```
app.angularModule.factory = ('dataService', function (breeze, logger) {
```

The data service factory should be defined in the same manner as you did with the logger factory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm dyslexic and dysgraphic  and I actually stared for 5 min in those 2 lines before I noticed '='